# How to query if a box is within an rtree

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

#### Question

Why does my query to find if a `box` is within an `rtree` return an empty result?

#### Explanation

Take the linestring

```
LINESTRING(1 1, 2 2)
```

and two polygons

```
POLYGON((0 0,0 1,1 1,1 0,0 0))
POLYGON((0 0,0 3,3 3,3 0,0 0))
```

I can use `boost::geometry::witin()` to query if the linestring is within either polygon (and it works)

However, if I create an `rtree` of the polygons, and put a `box` around the `linestring`, querying if the `box` is `within` the `rtree` returns an empty result.

#### Example

Here's an example showing both the working `bg::within(line, polygon)`, and the non-working `rtree.query(bgi::within( line_box1 ), ...)`

```
void rtree_within() {

  typedef bgm::point< double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian > point;
  typedef bgm::box<point> box;
  typedef bgm::linestring<point> line;
  typedef bgm::polygon<point> polygon;

  typedef std::pair<box, unsigned> value;

  bgi::rtree<value, bgi::quadratic<16> > rtree;
  std::vector<value> result_s;

  polygon poly1;
  polygon poly2;
  line line1;

  bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((0 0,0 1,1 1,1 0,0 0))", poly1);
  bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((0 0,0 3,3 3,3 0,0 0))", poly2);
  bg::read_wkt("LINESTRING(1 1, 2 2)", line1);

  std::cout << "line2 in poly1: " << bg::within(line1, poly1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "line2 in poly3: " << bg::within(line1, poly2) << std::endl;

  // boxes to insert into rtree
  box poly_box1 = bg::return_envelope<box>( poly1 );
  rtree.insert(std::make_pair(poly_box1, 0));

  box poly_box2 = bg::return_envelope<box>( poly2 );
  rtree.insert(std::make_pair(poly_box2, 2));

  // box around the line
  box line_box1 = bg::return_envelope<box>( line1 );

  std::cout << "poly_box1: " << bg::wkt( poly_box1 ) << std::endl; // returns 0
  std::cout << "poly_box2: " << bg::wkt( poly_box2 ) << std::endl; // returns 1
  std::cout << "line_box1: " << bg::wkt( line_box1 ) << std::endl;

  rtree.query(bgi::within( line_box1 ), std::back_inserter( result_s ));
  std::cout << "line_box1 within rtree - size: " << result_s.size() << std::endl;
  // result_s is empty (size == 0)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call free function `within(geom1,geom2)` it returns TRUE if `geom1` is inside `geom2`. But when you read reference about using `within` as predicate

> Generate a predicate defining Value and Geometry relationship. Value will be returned by the query if bg::within(Indexable, Geometry) returns true.

so you are trying to check whether `indexable` is inside `geometry`, and the result is false [indexable is rect, geometry is line]. You should use `contains` predicate instead `within` using rtree. `contains` predicate is equivalent to `bg::within(Geometry, Indexable)` then your code works as expected.

Comment: yes that appears to be the solution, although the reasoning is not intuitive to me at the moment given [the examples in their documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes/queries.html). I'll go back to the drawing-board and try and understand it again.